# Visio 2010 - foreign keys with different column names

Tags: database-design, modeling, visio

I'm creating a database model using Visio 2010. Is it possible to display a foreign key with a different column name than the linked column in the other table with Visio?
Thanks

Comment: Click on the relationship arrow and choose `Foreign key role name`

Comment: That was easy enough. Thanks, Damir.